# How can I design a REST Api to provide appointments from different point of views

Tags: api, rest

I am currently trying to find the right api design for an appointment-service that provides appointments from different point of views. My application has the following entities/roles:

- a patient is able to create appointment at different facilities
- a patient is allowed to see its own appointments
- a care provider is assigned to a specific facility
- a patient is able to share appointment details with facilities
- a care provider is allowed to see appointments from patient that shared appointment details with the care providers facility

the appointment-service therefore has different endpoints

**1) get appointments filtered by patient**
This endpoint has the following purpose: filter the appointment database by patientId. It is important that the logged in patient is only able to access its own appointments.

Here are my ideas for the endpoint:
A) GET /appointments?patientId={patientId}
The service has to verify that the given patientId is equal to the id from logged in user.
B) GET /patients/{patientId}/appointments
The patient is not really a resource in the appointment. This is why I am not sure that this endpoint is the right fit.
C) GET /appointments
The patientId is taken from the user token before accessing the db. It feels difficult to understand, since the query parameter is hidden from outside.

**2) get appointments filtered by facility shared with care provider**
This endpoint is a little bit difficult to describe. A care provider would like to see, which appointments take place at the facility he or she is working for. Therefore, the appointment-service should filter the appointments by facility id. On top of that, the care provider is only able to see appointments from patients that share their information with this facility. So we have a second filter criteria.

Here are my thoughts:

A) /appointments?facilityId={facilityId}
The service needs to:

- verify if the logged in user works for the facility
- check which patient share the data with that facility
- filter the db by facilityId and patientIds

B) /facilities/{facilityId}/appointments
Same todos as A). Just a different representation

C) GET /appointments

- retrieve the facility for the logged in user
- check which patient share the data with that facility
- filter the db by facilityId and patientIds
  again, it feels difficult to understand the endpoint

D) GET /care-providers/{careProviderId}/appointments
same todos as C). Just a different representation

To sum it up. What is the best why to include permission handling on a data level into REST APIs? It is easy to grant permissions on Method/Endpoint level, but difficult to provide access on data level. It least, it is hard for me.

Thank you all in advance
Michel

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best why to include permission handling on a data level into REST APIs?

Use the resource identifier to identify the resource.

Use the value of the Authorization field of the HTTP request to determine if the request should be authorized.

---

```
/appointments?patientId={patientId} 
/patients/{patientId}/appointments
```

Either of these identifiers is *fine*.  The first one is more convenient when you are working with HTML forms.  The second is more convenient when you want to use relative references to identify other resources in the `/patients/{patientId}` resource hierarchy.

> The patient is not really a resource in the appointment.

Not important - there's no constraint that says the hierarchy of identifiers in your resource model must align with your domain model or data model.

```
/appointments
```

This one works, but it doesn't have the same simplicity as the other two.  Instead of the representations being selected using the target URI alone, you now introduce additional variation based on Authorization.  HTTP does have mechanisms for describing responses that are sensitive to information in the request metadata, but Authorization is a special exception to that rule.

In summary, the first two options work because that's how it's all supposed to work.  The third option works as a consequence of a bunch of special rules around Authorization.

---

```
/appointments?facilityId={facilityId}
/facilities/{facilityId}/appointments
```

Those are both *fine* (same argument as before).  The fact that you need a complicated join in your database is an implementation detail.

```
/appointments
```

Same objections as above.

```
/care-providers/{careProviderId}/appointments
```

Again, same objection - if you need to dig around in the Authorization header to figure out the right representation to use, then you are further from "simple".

---

To offer some context: in a code review, I'd bless without comment either of the designs that include all of the information you need in the URI.

But if you were to choose one of the spellings that depends on the Authorization header, I'd insist on a Decision Record that demonstrates that you understand the implications of the current HTTP standards and the consequences of the different options available.